# Adding FileUpload control via code-behind

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, controls, code-behind

Because of the environment I work in I need to add controls to a page via code-behind.  I have done it dozens of times.  For some reason the FileUpload control is giving me grief.  here is my code:

```
FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
fileUpload.ID = "FileUploadControl";
this.Controls.Add(fileUpload);
```

The page looks as though it is timing out and display this error, "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

When I remove the last line (the Add), then the page renders just fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned which event handler you have used. Please try this,

```
 FileUpload file;
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  file= new FileUpload();
  PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(file);
 }
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if(file.HasFile)
   {
    file.SaveAs(MapPath("~/" + file.FileName));
   }
 }
```

Comment: I added the event handler but found that the control is not exposing things like HasFile, FileName, SaveAs, or any of the FileUpload properties.  Why would they be missing?